# Return a value to PHP which has called a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, svg

So........I am processing a PHP array which contains embedded SVG elements. I need to detect which user screen is being used so that I can constrain the svg elements to the display - 3 acrross for a laptop / PC, 2 for an iPad and 1 for a mobile phone.

So currently I have coded a simple call to a Javascript function from the PHP. But I need to be able to return a value, based on the device identified, to the PHP for further processing of the array in PHP.

Is this the correct way or is there another method that I should research?
Currently with the Javascript function and PHP are in the same file - SecureReadAllExercises.php

Javascript function finddevice() called from php file:

```
    function finddevice()
    {
    var width = screen.width;
    if (width==375) 
    {
        alert("Hello mobile phone");
        //need to return data to the php section in the php file
    }
    if (width>375 && width<1680) 
    {
        alert("Hello ipad");
        //need to return data to the php section in the php file
    }
    if (width==1680) 
    {
        alert("Hello desktop");
        //need to return data to the php section in the php file
    }
    }//end of javascript function scope
```

php code used to call javascript function:

```
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    finddevice();
     </script>';
```

Comment: you should use if and else condition , also check you got value in `screen.width` or not.

Comment: You should use ajax to send the data back to php, the great thing about ajax is that you can also have a callback.

Comment: Sounds like a task you can solve with asynchronous javascript and XML - in short: AJAX. Another possible solution could be @css media roules to display different images in your content depending on the screen resolution. With CSS media roules there is no need for javascript / php functionality.

Comment: Can you use $(window).on('resize', function(){ }); to identify device on screen change?

Comment: Have you included the js file in ur php file ??

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned - users on Iphone iPad and laptop see the alert - so detection is working.

Comment: I will research Ajax to see if it is  a simple technology as I only need a simple integer return to use ing the next stage of processing the PHP array

Comment: The current javascript filk is contained within the php file. For tidiness I can separate to different files foe easy maintenance.